8b/10b encoding disparity bit
Looking through the Wikipedia page on 8b/10b encoding, it lists a series of values for disparity bits of both -1 and +1. I have designed what I believe to be a working encoder, but what exactly is a disparity bit? The page says a disparity bit is needed to maintain DC balance(equal amount of 0s and 1s), but I do not understand how this is implemented in hardware with a given 8-bit input value.

Is it the term disparity "bit" that confuses you? There's no physical bit, the "running disparity" as its called is just a property of the data stream that needs to be kept track of.

You're questioning what disparity is, having read the Wikipedia article on 8b/10b encoding.
That same article already has a 'Running disparity' section that describes well and in detail what 8b/10b disparity is. It explains why it's needed, how it works and gives examples. It starts:

8b/10b coding is DC-free, meaning that the long-term ratio of ones and
zeros transmitted is exactly 50%. To achieve this, the difference
between the number of ones transmitted and the number of zeros
transmitted is always limited to ±2, and at the end of each symbol, it
is either +1 or −1. This difference is known as the running disparity
(RD).


Thank you for the answer. I thought it was something like a STOP/START bit(think I2C).

Fibre Channel uses 8B/10B encoding to created Ordered Sets.
Fibre Channel network protocols about the Primitives explains that different values can used used for the End Of Frame (EOF) primitive to allow the transmitter to maintain the running disparity after each frame:

Note 1: The first parameter byte of the EOF primitive can have one of four different values (8A, 95, AA, or B5). This is done so that the EOF primitive can rebalance the disparity of the whole frame. The remaining two parameter bytes define whether the frame is ending normally, terminating the transfer, or is to be aborted due to an error.

The Seagate Product Manual Fibre Channel Interface Table 4: Frame delimiters shows how which Ordered Set which is set depends upon the Beginning running disparity:

So, to maintain a neutral disparity requires consideration at the protocol level.
